# Тире или запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

"Что ни делается (—) все к лучшему" — какой знак тут правильно поставить: тире или запятую?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы поставила тире. Очень уж тут интонация "говорящая".

Answer (score 0):

Кроме того,здесь есть обобщающее слово "все",которое также лояльно относится к постановки тире.